Why is my GPU malfunctioning during startup?
This issue was previously posted on the Lubuntu subreddit, and the person who graciously spent time helping me figure it out told me to share it on here, because we ran out of ideas. I hope someone on here will have come across something like it before.
Please check out the original thread with all the stuff we tried out.
What we ended up finding out is that the issue most likely stems from the GPU, but installing the additional drivers didn't fix anything. Another weird thing is that the GUI only rarely has issues beyond that. Here is a link to some logs showing what is going on: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/hYhHxNGfXp/
Here is a description of the issue:
I set up Lubuntu 22.04.4 (the latest LTS build back when I did it) on my 2008 Unibody MacBook Pro, and I have a weird issue that I am struggling to figure out on my own.
The issue most likely doesn't stem from the quality of the download, as I spent a while figuring out whether my sha256sum hash was correct (see this post). I ended up using the ISO I got off zsync. Please do ask questions if you think it might come from there anyway.
Anytime I boot up Lubuntu, I end up with this or this. Notice how the cursor is displayed in the middle of the screen (it can't be moved). Sorry for the janky phone pictures of the screen, you'll understand I can't take screenshots. It turns out that when I get to that point, I can type out my password and log in. This hints at something being wrong with the login page (which I do sometimes see properly).
I also have an issue where I need to try a few times every time I boot up the laptop, because it simply freezes before getting to a point where I can log in. I think that's a separate issue so I might ask about it in a different post another time, but for all I know it could be related so I'm mentioning it here anyway.

The logs reveal several issues... There seems to be crashing bugs in at least two drivers, and the display manager doesn't support the current version of Qt library.
I would try different version of "nouveau" driver or falling back to standard VGA driver, if there isn't supported version for your graphics chip.
Out-of-bound access in the other driver needs more investigation from the kernel developers or the assigned maintainer of the respective driver. See the log line mentioning "bcmwl/6.30.223.271+bdcom".

Thank you, Mika  I will look into those.

Hi again! I am struggling to find a list of Nouveau versions and the supported hardware. How would you go about finding out if a graphics chip has a corresponding version of Nouveau available? If I input sudo ubuntu-drivers list it only shows "bcmwl-kernel-source". I also installed "nouveau-firmware (20091212-0ubuntu1)", which did not seem to be there already, but after a reboot the issue does not seem to be fixed, including in the logs.

What I know about Ubuntu releases and display adapters is that both needs to be from same era... However the logs suggest that some of the files are too new, which means first step would be to try display manager that doesn't use Qt and then revert to standard VGA driver to eliminate any bugs in Nouveau driver. With nVidia cards only thing you need to know is the GPU architecture and each driver version supports subset of architectures.

This is very helpful, thanks. I ended up finding this and this. I'll play around and see how far I can get, and I'll report back.

I came to a solution thanks to your help. It seems that you were right to think that Qt was causing issues. I wrote a response to my own post below so people can easily find the information in the future.

The solution that eventually worked was as shown below. What made the difference is point 3, I only included the rest because it's unclear from the post itself what the final setup is.
1- Reinstalling Nouveau with 
sudo apt install nouveau-firmware 
2- Re-enabling the Additional Drivers; 
3- Replacing the current display manager (SSDM) with XDM: 
sudo apt install xdm 
The terminal should automatically display a menu asking you which display manager to use, and you simply need to select XDM with the arrow keys and press the enter key.
4- Rebooting the computer.
Getting the Nvidia driver directly from their website did not work as it conflicts with Nouveau in a way that I could not figure out. If you let the Nvidia installer disable Nouveau, do:
rm /usr/lib/modprobe.d/nvidia-installer-disable-nouveau.conf
rm /etc/modprobe.d/nvidia-installer-disable-nouveau.conf

Amazingly, this seems to also have fixed the other issue I mentioned at the very end of my post.
Thank you to Mika Lindqvist and u/wxl on Reddit for the invaluable help!
